# Laravel: populate a form with properties coming from multiple models

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5

I am trying to build a form to edit the information of offices. This form is build using information coming from two models: Office and Address. Like you see in the image fields marked with 1 belongs to address model, the ones marked with 2 belongs to Offices

[image]

An Office has one Address

**office.php**

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

An address belongs to an Office

**address.php**

```
public function office()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Office');
}
```

Now, in order to populate the edit view I need to bind two models to a form!

I have tried this:

```
{!! Form::model($element, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['AdminofficeController@update', $element->slug ],'files'=>true]) !!} 

{!!Form::label('image', 'Upload a Featured Image') !!}
{!!Form::file('image', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))!!}

...here fields from office model...

{!! Form::label('street', 'Street:', array('class' => 'pt-3'))!!}
{!! Form::text($element->address->street, null, array('class'=>'form-control' )) !!}
 ... here other fields ...

{!!Form::submit('Edit Büro', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block')) !!}
{!!Form::close() !!}
```

But I get the following error:

**Property [street] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\laragon\www\domain\resources\views\dashboard\bueros\edit.blade.php)**

This line does not solve the problem

```
{!! Form::text($element->address->street, null, array('class'=>'form-control' )) !!}
```

I have var_dump te collection and indeed, it has an street property, it means the relation is working ok.

As far as I know I can't bind two models to one form (not in HTML)

**How do I populate a form with properties coming from multiple models?**

I would hate to make two forms one to edit Address and another for the name of the office.

Comment: The error actually offers a hint to the source of your problem. The `$element->address` relation should contain an `Address` model instance according to your definition, not a `Collection` instance as the error indicates. You might want to have a look why that is.

Comment: @Bogdan, thanks for the answer. I have changed the structure of the model, so now it gets an instance of address

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but here's an answer that works for me.

Your first form line:

```
{!! Form::model($element, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['AdminofficeController@update', $element->slug ],'files'=>true]) !!}
```

should be amended to:

```
{!! Form::model($building->toArray() + $address->toArray(), ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['AdminofficeController@update', $element->slug ],'files'=>true]) !!}
```

I'm not 100% certain that the ->toArray() is required but this does work for forms that I have with multiple models that I want to be auto-populated.

Note: the $building and $address variables would be whatever you have used in your code.